# How to place functions with parameters into an array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

So I am programming a small bot that will do different actions, like moving, interacting, grabbing, and more in a game. I made all of these actions to be functions of the same format (bool Move(int direction), bool Interact(int type), ...) and I wanted to put them into an array so that the bot only has to check through them once every time it wants to do something.

I've tried solutions I found on the internet (for void functions) like using a typedef, or this:

```
    bool Move(int type);
    bool Interact(int type);

    bool (*baseAction[2])(int type) = { Move, Interact };
```

but it doesn't seem to work, it says that a value of type "bool (Character::*)(int type)" *cannot be used to initialize an entity of type "bool* (*)(int type)"

If someone understands how to make these, I would be extra grateful if you could also tell me how to do this on dynamic arrays like std::vector or std::list

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: If these functions are non-static members in some class, you should mention that in your question.

Comment: An alternative to storing member functions can be making those functions `static` – static functions you *can* assign to ordinary function pointers, though you then need an explicit replacement for the implicit `this` parameter of member functions, i.e. you'd add `Character& instance` as an additional parameter.

Comment: Is an array of pointer-to-member-functions really more desirable than a member function that calls the functions? Either situation requires multiple touches and neither seems totally ideal. But at least a member function call seems to make more sense. At least, given what little information there is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pointer to member.

```cpp
class Character {
   public:
    bool Move(int type);
    bool Interact(int type);
};
bool (Character::*baseAction[2])(int type) = {&Character::Move,
                                              &Character::Interact};

int main() {
    Character character;
    for (int type = 0; type < 2; type++) {
        (character.*baseAction[type])(type);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Indeed – obviously they are unkown to question author, though, and she/he might yet need be hinted to differing call syntax (`(c.*f)(12)`/`(c->*f)(10)` with parentheses being necessary due to function call having higher precedence).